# Bring my wife to Germany

Tags: germany, immigration, surinder-singh

I am a British citizen and I have a wife and children who are living in Afghanistan.

I would like to bring my wife, an Afghan national, to Germany, under the Surinder Singh route.

My three children, who are 6, 8, and 9 years old, want to remain in Afghanistan and live with my mother, at least for the time being.

Is German immigration going to ask me about my children, and why I didn't request that they immigrate with my wife? Is this going to be a problem?

Comment: I've edited your question so that is a bit clearer, Asif. Should I have misinterpreted, you can undo/roll back the changes.

Comment: @GregHewgill is it wise to include the surinder-singh tag on a question that doesn't actually concern the surinder-singh ruling?

Comment: @phoog: Yes, good point, I had not read this one carefully enough. But it *is* mentioned in the question, even if it's not applicable.

Answer (score 1):

As a British citizen moving to Germany, you do not need to be concerned with the Surinder Singh judgment.  This case only applies to EU citizens who are moving *to their country of citizenship* with family members who are not EU citizens.  It will therefore apply to you if you want to move to the UK after living in Germany.

In your case, you are automatically covered by the freedom of movement directive (2004/38/EC).  This gives you a right to move to Germany that can only be denied under very limited circumstances.  You also have a right to bring your wife and children with you, but it's not necessary to bring them all at the same time.

I do not know how likely it is that German immigration will ask about your children.  It should not be a problem, though, if they do, as long as your mother is in a position to care for the children.

Comment: Thank you very much sir from your lovely information how easy it is to bring my wife from germany to uk.

Comment: @Asif that's a different question and should be [asked](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) as such.  You'll want to start at https://www.gov.uk/family-permit/surinder-singh, but note that this is all likely to change as a consequence of the UK's decision to leave the European Union.  If you still have questions after reading that page, please ask here.